# Chaining Transforms in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am currently having trouble chaining a rotation transformation in a D3 line chart. The parameters for the origin are dynamically updated and I am not sure what I need to do so that each call to this batch of code rotates the line a further 15 degrees. I have tried adding a plus in front of the rotate string as per another answer I saw but it throws an error. Ideally I would like the transition to animate each time from the updated rotated position(like the hand of a clock moving).

```
//select the path I want to transform this works for a single time

d3.select(".demandPath1")
.transition()
.duration(2000)
.attr("transform",`rotate(-15,${xScale([demandX[5])},{yScale(demandY[5])})`)
```

This code will be called on the press of a button which should continually rotate the line in increments of 15 degrees starting each time from the new position.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a variable to store the string:

   var existingTransformString="";
2. Use string concat method to append the new string to the existing string- which has the correct transforms stored i.e. those that have been applied to the existing path element:

function rotate(direction){
    if(direction==="increase"){
         let string = `rotate(15,${xScale(demandX[5])},${yScale(demandY[5])})`;
         existingTransformString = existingTransformString.concat(string);
          d3.select(".demandPath1").attr("transform",existingTransformString);
     }else{
       let string = `rotate(-15, ${xScale(demandX[5])},${yScale(demandY[5])})`;
       existingTransformString = existingTransformString.concat(string);
      d3.select(".demandPath1").attr("transform",existingTransformString);
   }
  }